# Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <div> cannot appear as a child of <tr> using React-bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-table

I have this code. This and more is in the `return` statement of the `render()` method

```
<Table striped bordered condensed hover responsive>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>Imie Nazwisko/Nazwa firmy</th>
        <th style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>ID</th>
        <th style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>Raporty</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {
        this.state.users && this.state.users.map((user, i) => (
            <tr key={user.id}>
                <td>
                    {user.userType === 'person' ? `${user.person.firstName} ${user.person.lastName}` : user.company.name}
                </td>
                <td>{user.id}</td>
                <Table striped bordered hover responsive>
                    <tbody>
                    {
                        user.reports.map(report => (
                            <tr key={report.id}>
                                <td>{report.id}</td>
                            </tr>
                        ))
                    }
                    </tbody>
                </Table>
            </tr>
        ))
    }
    </tbody>
</Table>
```

And this error code:

```
Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <div> cannot appear as a child of <tr>.
    in div (created by Table)
    in Table (at ReportsComponent.js:59)
    in tr (at ReportsComponent.js:54)
    in tbody (at ReportsComponent.js:51)
    in table (created by Table)
    in div (created by Table)
    in Table (at ReportsComponent.js:43)
    in ReportsComponent (at NavigationComponent.js:67)
```

So the problem is I am not creating the div myself. I can see that Table is creating the div that's throwing the error.

I am using the [Table](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/table/) component from [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/).

This code looks OK in the browser, and seems to work, but the error is just irritating. How can I solve it?

Comment: you might want to look at [Nested Table](https://github.com/AllenFang/react-bootstrap-table/issues/1134)

Comment: When you add the `responsive` prop to a `React Bootstrap` table, they wrap the `table` in a `div` which is causing the conflict with your table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React Bootstrap generates a Table in form of `div` when adding the responsive property. To avoid this warning (note, not a blocking error) you could wrap the `Table` component in a `td`.

Or if you prefer you can write a wrapper around React Bootstrap's Table to make sure it gets surrounded by `td` if the responsive property is passed in.